# Binding ItemsSource programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime

What is the equivalent of this in c# code?

```
<ListView
    x:Name="taskItemListView"
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding taskItems}">
...
</ListView>
```

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Path = new PropertyPath("taskItems");

DependencyProperty dp = DependencyProperty.Register("itemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(object), null);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(taskItemListView, dp, b);
```

**Edit**:

Based on @sa_ddam213's answer, this worked:

```
Binding dataContextBinding = new Binding();
dataContextBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");
dataContextBinding.Source = itemListView;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(taskItemListView, ListView.DataContextProperty, dataContextBinding );

Binding sourceBinding = new Binding();
sourceBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("taskItems");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(taskItemListView, ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, sourceBinding );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somthing like this should work:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(taskItemListView, ListView.DataContextProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem") { Source = itemListView});
BindingOperations.SetBinding(taskItemListView, ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("taskItems") { Source = this });
```

Note: "Source = this" `this` equals the class that is holding the `taskItems`, `SelectedItem`

Comment: Thanks, it works wonders! Just 2 minor corrections: the class Binding has only one constructor that takes no arguments, and turns out there was no need to set the second Binding's source. I've edited my question.

Comment: Binding does work with a string arg, using it now in a .NET4.0 project, link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx

Comment: Not on a WinRT app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209820.aspx#constructors.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is by SetValue:

```
taskItemListView.SetValue(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, this.Source);
```

More information at here: [DependencyObject.SetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue)