# How to bind ListView ItemsSource programmatically in C++/WinRT, WinUI 3

Tags: listview, binding, c++-winrt, winui-3, itemssource

I'm trying to programmatically set up a binding for a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) [ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-itemscontrol-itemssource) in WinUI 3 and was hoping that something similar to how it's done in Wpf ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898717/1280961)) is possible but i cannot find a `ItemsSourceProperty` in `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView` or `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::IItemsControl`.

I did bind it successfully in Xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}"
```

so i was hoping that it's also possible in code.

Am i searching at the wrong place? Is it possible to do this in code?

Example:

```
if (auto list = GetTemplateChild(L"myList").try_as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView>())
{
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::Binding binding;
    binding.Mode(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::BindingMode::OneWay);
    binding.Path(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyPath(L"MySourceProperty"));
    binding.Source(mySourceControl);
    list.SetBinding(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView::ItemsSourceProperty(), binding);
}
```

Comment: Probably not relevant, but just to be sure: Is this for WinUI 2 or 3?

Comment: @IInspectable It's for WInUI 3.

Comment: Either way, you'll want to set the [`ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-itemscontrol-itemssource) property. Make sure to have the language selector set to *C++/WinRT* to see the signature for both the getter and setter.

Comment: @IInspectable msvc outputs `error C2039: 'ItemsSourceProperty': is not a member of 'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::IItemsControl'` .
Am i missing a header or something? Where can i find the "language selector"?
(It would find it for `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty` but that's not what i'm after)

Comment: I can't comment on code I cannot see, so I don't know where `ItemsSourceProperty` is being accessed. You'll want to set the `ItemsSource` property. If your listview instance is called `lv`, and your source `src`, you'd have to invoked `lv.ItemsSource(src);`. I believe you can get a compatible items source from the [`single_threaded_observable_vector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/single-threaded-observable-vector) function template.

Comment: @IInspectable I did that to test but now i want to set up a binding. As far as i understand this, [`FrameworkElement.SetBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.setbinding?view=winrt-22621) needs a `DependencyProperty` which seems to be returned by convention from a method with a Property suffix. What am i missing?

I added the code i'm testing with.

Comment: I get it now: You're trying to establish a XAML binding (what `{Binding ...}` does, rather than `{x:Bind ...}`) in code. Phew, that's way out of my comfort zone. Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property#using-the-binding-markup-extension-with-cwinrt) help in understanding the underlying principles?

Comment: @IInspectable This is weird; i compiled before with `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty` and got `error C2039`; then i compiled again with `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty` just for testing and got `error C3779: 'winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined` but now switching back to `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty` it compiles fine? Maybe it was just a compiler hiccup.

Comment: Complex as C++ is, compiler hiccups are rarely the explanation for an issue. This reads more like something went haywire in the build system (there's a lot going on before the compiler even gets a go, gathering dependencies, generating code, ...). The second error is particularly insightful: It's *actually* [a linker error that got promoted to a compiler error](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190530-00/?p=102529). You may still be missing an `#include` after all. Though, the entire `Windows::UI`/`Microsoft::UI`-dichotomy is straight up confusing (it's not just you).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's simple; instead of the convenience from Wpf where the ItemsSource can be taken directly from the Listview, [`winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssourceproperty?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) is needed here.

Example:

```
if (auto list = GetTemplateChild(L"myList").try_as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView>())
{
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::Binding binding;
    binding.Mode(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::BindingMode::OneWay);
    binding.Path(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyPath(L"MySourceProperty"));
    binding.Source(mySourceControl);
    list.SetBinding(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemsControl::ItemsSourceProperty(), binding);
}
```